# Date formating in handson table

Tags: javascript, angular, handsontable, rhandsontable

I am using handson table lib in my angular project.  have a date column and i want the dates to be formatted like that DD/MM/YYYY at the init of the table but unfortunately nothing is happened and even when i call afterRender() in angular's hooks(after view init and after view checked ) it tolds me cannot render of undefined so it's like the table is undefined at this time.
So what is the sollution for that? 
this is  afterRender method

```
private afterRender( ) {
  console.log("rendere")
  this.hotRegisterer.getInstance(this.idTableau).render();
  this.hotRegisterer.getInstance(this.idTableau).validateCells();
}
```

this is my settings

```js
hotSettings: Handsontable.GridSettings = {
  height: MajStockComponent.HANDSON_TABLE_HEIGHT,
  width: MajStockComponent.HANDSON_TABLE_WIDTH,
  stretchH: 'all',
  rowHeaderWidth: MajStockComponent.HANDSON_TABLE_ROW_HEADER_WIDTH,
  colWidths: MajStockComponent.HANDSON_TABLE_COL_WIDTH,
  colHeaders: MajStockComponent.HANDSON_TABLE_IS_COL_HEADER,
  licenseKey: ConstantesNuc.LICENCE_KEY_TABLE_HANDSOME_TABLE,
  language: ConstantesNuc.HANDSOME_FR,
  columns: [
    {
      data: "code",
      type: 'text',
      readOnly: true
    },
    {
      data: "num",
      type: 'text',
      readOnly: true
    },
    {
      data: "date",
      type: 'date',
      readOnly: true,
      dateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      correctFormat: true,
    },
  ],
  nestedHeaders: [
    [{
      label: '',
      colspan: 3
    }],
    ['Code ', 'Num ', 'Date']
  ],
  afterLoadData: (bool) => {
    this.afterRender();
  },
}
```

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: how can i use it here  ?

Comment: Use simple angular date pipe for Data format : https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have make to custom cell render for your date cell.

```
 columns: [
    {
      data: "code",
      type: 'text',
      readOnly: true
    },
    {
      data: "num",
      type: 'text',
      readOnly: true
    },
    {
      data: "date",
      type: 'date',
      readOnly: true,
      renderer: function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
      dateCell = value,  // format your date value with custom pipe.
      return dateCell;
      }
    },
  ],
```

Comment: if i will use a pipe it must be decalred in the constructor but i cant call this.datePipe in the rendrer